# Why do not my entities want to tie together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to tie a comment to the ticket. To do that, I have created a one to many relationship between Ticket to comment.
However, I get an error message stating that.

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Commenents_Tickets_Ticket_Id". The conflict occurred in database "NewTracker", table "dbo.Tickets", column 'Ticket_Id'.

I guess it's because I do not get my ticket_id when I make a comment. To try to solve this task, I have included ticket_Id which you can see in the view. (asp-route-Id="@Model.Ticket_Id).

In my view I am already inside my ticket where I want to make a comment as you can see in my url I have an Id `/Ticket/Info/32` . I therefore thought it was possible to use asp-route-Id="@Model.Ticket_Idto be able to link to the ticket id?

Here are my views:

```
@model WebApplication20.ViewModel.CommentVM

@{
    Layout = "_Dashboard";
    var title = "About Ticket";
}

<html>

<body id="page-top">
    <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4><strong>Ticket Status</strong></h4> Created @Model.Ticket.TicketCreated
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Name:</strong>@Model.Ticket.TicketName </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Descripton: </strong> @Model.Ticket.TicketDescription</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Priority:</strong> @Model.Ticket.TicketPriority</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Type:</strong> @Model.Ticket.TicketType</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Status:</strong> @Model.Ticket.TicketStatus</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="card shadow mx-auto m-3" style="width: 42rem;">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4><strong>Comments</strong></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 p-4">
                <form asp-controller="Ticket" asp-action="Comments" asp-route-Id="@Model.Ticket_Id" >
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Comment.Message" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Comment.Message" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Comment.Message" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input  asp-controller="Ticket" asp-action="Comments" asp-route-Id="@Model.Ticket_Id" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        @*TABLE*@

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Area Chart -->
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7">
                <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                    <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
                    <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Current Comments</h6>

                    </div>
                    @if (Model.Comments.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        Message
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Submitter
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Created
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                
                                @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
                                {
                                    <tr>

                                        <td width="10%">
                                            @comment.Message
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="10%">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="10%">
                                            @comment.Created
                                        </td>



                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <h5 class="text-secondary m-1">There are no comments for this ticket yet..</h5>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @*END TABLE*@

    </div>

    <div class="text-center p-3">
        <a asp-controller="Ticket" asp-route-Id="@Model.Ticket.Ticket_Id" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-lg text-white w-30">Edit</a>
        <a asp-controller="Ticket" asp-route-Id="@Model.Ticket.Ticket_Id" asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg text-white w-30">Delete</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="/TemplateInfo/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/TemplateInfo/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="/TemplateInfo/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="/TemplateInfo/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my controller for the view I want to make a comment

```
public IActionResult Info(int id)
{
    CommentVM t = new CommentVM();
    t.Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Ticket_Id == id);
    t.Comments = _db.Commenents.Where(f => f.Ticket_Id == id);
    return View(t);
}
```

My controller where I should be able to make a comment:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Comments(CommentVM obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {    
        _db.Comments.Add(obj.Comment);
        _db.SaveChanges(); <--- Here are where the conflict occurs
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View();
}
```

This is my view model:

```
public class CommentVM
{
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public int Ticket_Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    public Comments Comment { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

But I still get an error that it can not bind to a ticket_id?

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Did you save your ticket BEFORE adding the comment?

Comment: Yes i do. My ticket is already saved when i want to make my comment

Comment: I  see you  are getting list of comments in your info action, but I can see only one comment message in the view. Can you post the  CommonVm and the whole view pls? Otherwise it is hard to understand what are you doing.

Comment: I will do it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add hidden field to your view, inside of form tags

```
<input type="hidden"  asp-for="Comment.TicketId" value="@Model.Comment.TicketId" />
```

and init new comment in your info action before passing

```
public IActionResult Info(int id)
{
    CommentVM t = new CommentVM{ Comment= new Comment {TicketId=id} }};
    t.Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Ticket_Id == id);
    t.Comments = _db.Commenents.Where(f => f.Ticket_Id == id);
    return View(t);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Ok i see, I'm just wondering about one thing. When I set my input to hidden, the text field disappears. Should I add a text area or similar to be able to write a comment?

Comment: Thank you it solved my issue ! :) To solve my issue with the text area i just put a new text area with a submit button like this:   <textarea asp-for="Comment.Message" rows="5" style="resize:none;" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" btn btn-sucess>Submit</button>